# How to start a docker volume attached to local working directory in cli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

when I try and start a docker container with volume attached to the local working directory, it doesn't work. Here is the command I'm using"

```
docker run -v .:/app image_name rails s
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what does happen?  Can you use a local Ruby environment, maybe based on `rbenv` or `rvm`, and avoid the complexities of Docker here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app image_name rails s
```